# How to attach debugger to the Runtime WASM

Tags: runtime, wasm

Using **lldb** (like with VSCode), it is fairly easy to attach it to the client, allowing to debug the client side of the node. However, once the wasmtime is executing the Wasm Runtime, the debugger is not able to retrieve the information.

Using `--execution native` is a possible temporary solution but is not suitable to all cases. Moreover, the Native execution is meant to be removed at some point.

Comment: i'm not sure if it's related but i was recently trying to debug this code with breakpoints https://github.com/ltfschoen/kobold-test/pull/1/files in Visual Studio Code but it uses wasm-bindgen, and i read here that it's not yet possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67032785/how-to-debug-rust-and-webassembly-program-with-vscode-and-codelldb

Answer (score 1):

Another way of debugging your WASM runtime is to use [wasmi](https://github.com/paritytech/wasmi). Build the `cli` and run what you want to run. If something goes wrong and you cannot figure out what exactly, you can always add some logs to wasmi code. Or even make step-by-step execution logging values of interest